# TextInputLayout boxBackgroundColor not working after 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

The problem I have is when I want to set boxBackgroundColor on TextInputLayout on versions after'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02' of design library I don't see any changes and since I want to use ExposedDropdownMenu which is only supported in later versions, I can't seem to find any solutions. 
I've tried setting it in java and also in styles but no results.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text">

  <AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md#filled-box-default):

> Note: When using a filled text field with an `EditText` child that is not a
>   `TextInputEditText`, make sure to set the `EditText`'s `android:background` to
>   `@null`. This allows `TextInputLayout` to set a filled background on the
>   `EditText`.

Just use:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/primaryLightColor"
        ...>


      <AutoCompleteTextView
          android:background="@null"
          .../>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]